# How to use Add method with repository pattern while using related entities .Net Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping, repository-pattern

this is my product entity

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
       public string ProductName { get; set; }
       public string Description { get; set; }
       public string Img1 { get; set; }
       public string Img2 { get; set; }
       public string Img3 { get; set; }
       public decimal Price { get; set; }
       public int Stock { get; set; }

       //    Related Entities

       public Category Category { get; set; }
       public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    }
```

Category entity

```
public class Category : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Img { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

my IProductrepositoryinterface

```
 public interface IProductRepository
    {
        Task<Product> GetProductByIdAsync(int id);
        Task<IReadOnlyList<Product>> GetProductsAsync();
        Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync();
        void Add(Product product);
        void Update(Product product);
        void Delete(Product product);

    }
```

product repository

```
namespace Infrastructure
{
    public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
    {
       private readonly StoreContext _context;

        public ProductRepository(StoreContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(Product product)
        {
            _context.Add(product);
        }

        public void Delete(Product product)
        {
            _context.Remove(product);
        }

        public async Task<Product> GetProductByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Products.Include(c => c.Category)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<Product>> GetProductsAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Products.Include(p => p.Category).
            ToArrayAsync();
        }

        public async Task<bool> SaveChangesAsync()
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) > 0;
        }

        public void Update(Product product)
        {
            _context.Attach(product);
            _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

ProductController Post method

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddProduct(Product product)
        {
            try
            {
                if (product.Id == 0)
                {
                    var responseError = new ResponseError(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, "Fields cannot be empty.");
                    var response = new Response(false, null, responseError);
                    return BadRequest(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    _repository.Add(product);
                    await _repository.SaveChangesAsync();
                    var response = new Response(true, product, null);
                    return Ok(response);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var responseError = new ResponseError(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, e.Message);
                var response = new Response(false, null, responseError);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, response);
            }
        }
```

[image: Current json]
[image: our desired post method]
How can we change post method with only giving categoryName . What I m trying is making program understanding directly with category name without using categoryId ? [current error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL823.jpg) For now I am stuck with this error.

Answer (score 1):

So you want your HTTP request object to be different than your EF Entity.  This is a common pattern.  Typical solution is to have a separate set of types that define the contract for your API and map back and forth to your EF Entity types.

See eg [Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)